# Selenium: Unable to click a button of custom popup

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I tried to click a button of select files then submit button in the popup but it neither recognizes the popup nor the button in it.

For selecting the modal-content

```
driver.switchTo().frame("modal-content");
```

message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: No frame element found by name or id modal-content
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'RAUNAK-MA', ip: '192.168.2.200', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.frame(RemoteWebDriver.java:885)
    at newpackage1.newTest.main(newTest.java:41)
```

post removing the switch to and directly selecting the element

```
WebElement LinkCheckerbutton1 = driver.findElement(By.id("linkCheckerFileUpload"));
                    LinkCheckerbutton1.click();
```

Results:

```
  Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"linkCheckerFileUpload"}
      (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
    For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
    Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
    System info: host: 'RAUNAK-MA', ip: '192.168.2.200', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a..., userDataDir: C:\Users\RAUNAK~1.MAS\AppDa...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:65266}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: ignore, unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, version: 73.0.3683.103, webStorageEnabled: true}
    Session ID: 889a04bb870854aef890e9dcb55c7508
    *** Element info: {Using=id, value=linkCheckerFileUpload}
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:372)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:188)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
        at newpackage1.newTest.main(newTest.java:43)
```

Comment: Are you sure your popup is a `frame`? nowadays, it's more like a `div`. (ex: bootstrap)

Comment: can you share the url if it is public

Comment: Did you try adding a wait? If it's in a "dialog", then it likely takes a second to load the dialog and have the element appear and be interactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: No frame element found by name or id modal-content
```

...implies that there is no *frame element* by the *id* or *name* **modal-content**.

However it gives us a hint the desired element is within a *Modal Dialog Box*.

So to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#linkCheckerFileUpload"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[id='linkCheckerFileUpload']"))).click();
  ```